# Assign a value to a column based on list of indices

Tags: r

I'm working on Netflix data from Kaggle and the way it is formatted, there's 1 row with the movie ID followed by rows of customer id's and ratings for that movie. 
So the format would be:

```
1:
3245 4
5443 2
2:
4346 4
2345 5
```

where the row with only 1 number is a movie ID and the following rows are the customer ratings for that movie.
I'm trying to extract these movie IDs and just create another column in the customer rating that would hold the movie ID, but I'm not really sure how to do that.
I managed to create a list of all the indexes in which a movie id appears:

```
movie_title_index = which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

But I've been having trouble figuring out how to assign the item at that index to every row after that column. Here's what I've been able to come up with so far but it doesn't work:

```
df[rownames(df)>movie_title_index,]$movie_id = df$V1[movie_title_index]
```

Comment: can you post your data using `dput()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your data as follows:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(
    "1:",
    "3245 4",
    "5443 2",
    "2:",
    "4346 4",
    "2345 5"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Here is a solution using the tidyverse that breaks apart the string components and fills the MoveID downward.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(MoveID = str_extract(x,"^[[:digit:]](?=\\:)"),
         CustomedID = str_extract(x,"^[[:digit:]]+(?=\\s)"),
         Score = str_extract(x,"(?<=\\s)[[:digit:]]+$")) %>%
  fill(MoveID) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  select(-x)

#>
  MoveID CustomedID Score
1      1       3245     4
2      1       5443     2
3      2       4346     4
4      2       2345     5
```

Comment: You’re welcome. If this solved your problem, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.